# why, I'm getting some strange garbage values?

Tags: c++, file

When I'm trying to store & print an integer array with write(), I'm getting garbage values...But everything turns fine when I go with character array (instead of integer array).

*I'm new with File-Handling.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
int num[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
/* char num[20] = "This works fine";  */

std::ofstream fout;
fout.open("val.txt");
fout.write((char *)num, sizeof(num));
fout.close();

std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("val.txt");
char ch;

while (fin.get(ch))
{
    std::cout << ch << " ";
}

return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are in bytes. Integers are made of either 4 (32-bit) or 8 (64-bit) bytes. They can also be in little-endian (Intel) or big-endian (PowerPC) byte order.

In memory and in the disk file you wrote, `num[0]` is `char[4] {1, 0, 0, 0}`

What you did is perfectly fine if you wanted to write the binary representation of your in-memory data.

In your character at a time print loop, if you wanted to see the number value of each byte you will need to cast it to int before `cout` will format it correctly. The `char` type is printed as an ASCII character. The only values you would see of that are from 33 to 127 and it would be the numbers, symbols and letters.

Try this for output:

```
while (fin.get(ch))
{
    std::cout << (int)ch << " ";
}
```

Actually I would make a couple of other changes too and my version is like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int num[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

  {
    std::ofstream fout("val.txt", std::ios::binary);
    fout.write((char *)num, sizeof num);
  }

  {
    std::ifstream fin("val.txt", std::ios::binary);
    char ch;

    while (fin.get(ch)) {
      std::cout << (int)ch << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `sizeof()` yields the **size in bytes**, while the `fstream.wirte()` takes as a second parameter a **number of characters** to write, you overrun boundaries for the `num` and write to the file random contents of the memory.

You give to `write` the result of `number_of_elements * sizeof(element)` as a second argument.

Then the cast `(char *)` also introduces trouble. What do you expect it to write to your file? It better not be integers `0, 1, 2, ..., 9`. **Printable characters** will begin at the value `32` (space). If you want to have anything visible in your file. You should start from `33`.

Moreover, try this:

```
std::cout << sizeof(char) <<  " vs " << sizeof(int); // 1 vs 4
```

After the cast, the pointer to `char` (1 byte) will have to reinterpret and point to the memory that occupied by an `int` (4 bytes)...